# What is the correct math notation for the final solution while finding the rank of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, parametric

What are the respective different **ranks** of the matrix ?

I tried with all parameters $a,b$ and $c$ being zero , and then $c$ being $0$.
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
5 & a & b \\
c & 8 & 6 \end{array} \right)$$
Is this OK to get all possible solutions depending on and parameters $a,b$ and $c$, which are all real numbers?

Comment: what is your problem? please, try to be more clear about what your problem is

Comment: The solutions to what?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: depending on a,b and c parameters to find the RANK of the matrix

Comment: Have you tried Gauss-Jordan elimination to reduce the matrix and considered the different cases that occur when doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Applying Gauss-Jordan

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
5 & a & b \\
c & 8 & 6 \end{array} \right)$$

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & a-20 & b-15 \\
0 & 8-4c & 6-3c \end{array} \right)$$

Case 1: If $a\neq20$ then

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-15}{a-20} \\
0 & 8-4c & 6-3c \end{array} \right)$$

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-15}{a-20} \\
0 & 8-4c & 6-3c \end{array} \right)$$

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 3-\frac{4(b-15)}{a-20} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-15}{a-20} \\
0 & 0 & 6-3c-\frac{4(2-c)(b-15)}{a-20} \end{array} \right)$$

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{3a-4b}{a-20} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-15}{a-20} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{(2-c)(3a-4b)}{a-20} \end{array} \right)$$

If $c\neq2$ and $3a\neq4b$ then all are independent and you have rank 3.

If $c=2$ or $3a=4b$ then you have rank 2.

Case 2: If $a=20$ then

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & b-15 \\
0 & 8-4c & 6-3c \end{array} \right)$$

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & 8-4c & 6-3c \\
0 & 0 & b-15 \end{array} \right)$$

If $c=2$ and $b=15$ then rank 1.
If $c=2$ or $b=15$ then rank 2.

Edit:

Looking back at the second line we could have worked everything out from there:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & a-20 & b-15 \\
0 & 8-4c & 6-3c \end{array} \right)$$

If $a\neq20$ and $b\neq15$ and $c\neq2$ then rank 3.
If $c=2$ OR $a=20$ & $b=15$ then rank 2.
If $c=2$ and $a=20$ and $b=15$ then rank 1.